# Change camera config (fov, userHeight, orientation) when in VR mode

Tags: aframe

I'm using Aframe master branch and testing with OculusGo.

Is it possible to update some camera values as fov, userHeight and orientation (rotation) when entering in VR mode?

Thank you very much,
Daniele.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FOV cannot be changed in VR mode. It’s particular to each headset, provided by the WebVR API and not application configurable. To position and rotate the camera [use a rig](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/primitives/a-camera.html#manually-positioning-the-camera)